# Deploy Django on Plotly Dash Enterprise (Docker/Herokuish/Gunicorn/nginx)

Tags: python, django, heroku, plotly-dash

Good Evening,

I am attempting to install a Django and run the development server and production WSGI on [Dash Enterprise](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-enterprise).  I'll preface this with I am also fairly new to Python and Django but not programming.

From what I can tell the Dash Enterprise Stack runs a Heroku like containerized web container setup. Each of these containerized apps have a web accessible IDE and are able to run the development web server and are served up at domain.com/Workspaces/view/app_name/

When the code is pushed via git, the live app is viewable at domain.com/app_name/

Gunicorn is employed with nginx to run the production web server and is configured via a ProcFile in the root of the app.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app_name.wsgi
```

Other services at play appear to be Docker, Herokuish, and Dokku.

My code runs fine when tested locally, but when employed on the server, the development server gives me errors such as

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 16, 2022 - 23:35:45
Django version 4.0.5, using settings 'app_name.settings'
Starting development server at http://0:8050/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /Workspaces/view/app_name/
[16/Jun/2022 23:35:53] "GET /Workspaces/view/app_name/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2183
```

app_name/url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbAHI.png)

When I push via git, I'm able to see the unformatted domain.com/app_name/admin link but am unable to login.

I can't see the welcome page for Django on either the development server or the production when running the test app.

I was able to run a flask app with no issues, but Django is giving me headaches. It seems like the app is hosted underneath a URL path that is giving me fits. Any ideas for what I can look for and/or try to get this up and running?

Comment: Can you add urls.py of main folder as well as the project folder?

Comment: It's 100% boilerplate and unimpressive. Looking to proof of concept, so haven't done anything besides add the project and look at the pretty rocket ship image with no urls defined.

Comment: Can you add the Procfile config, most likely I am thinking it's nginx

Comment: Code for the procfile should be up above or are you referring to something else?